# How to install Java (not OpenJava) on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: software-installation, java, jdk, openjdk

Please help! I have downloaded the .deb version of Java SE JDK from this site: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk11-downloads.html This .deb file is saved in my Downloads folder.  When I double click the icon the Ubuntu Software Install page pops up, I hit install, but it never installs.

[image]

It shows up under the installed tab, but then it still says install on the far right column.
[image]

So I press Install again, and it says are you sure you want to remove it? If I click remove, it just disappears from Ubuntu Software. I have tried  `sudo dpkg -i jdk-11.07_linux-x64_bin.deb` but I get "dpkg: error: cannot access archive 'jdk-11.07_linux-x64_bin.deb': No such file or directory".

When trying to install using Terminal, I receive this error: `Oracle JDK 11 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java11-installer-local (--configure):
 installed oracle-java11-installer-local package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1`

`Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java11-installer-local
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Any ideas?
[image]

Nothing is in the java-11-oracle directory.
I have downloaded jdk-11.0.7_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz and placed it into /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local, but now when I run sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java I get an error Err:1 archive.ubuntu eoan InRelease Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu' 
[image]

Comment: should you do it in software center? Don't you want to install it on terminal?

Comment: Did you `cd` to the directory where the `.deb` file is saved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow these steps to install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jdk
```

And then you can choose which java version to use as default

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Comment: why do I get this when I run the last line, to set java 11 as default?                           
`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package oracle-java11-set-default-local is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'oracle-java11-set-default-local' has no installation candidate`

Comment: I have editted my answer for you to choose which java version you want as default.

Comment: I only have one alternative? Please see new screenshot as there are multiple java versions in /usr/lib/jvm directory.  `sudo update-alternatives --config java`  gives me **There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java**

Comment: yes you have only one alternative, because you installed only one version of java. If you have had more than one already you could choose of course.
I mean it give you chance to choose java version from your installed.
For example if you install java 12, you will have 2 options to choose.

Comment: And I think my answer deserved of being "accepted answer" :)

Comment: OK but can you please explain why I have so many versions of java in /usr/lib/jvm directory first?   Please see the final screenshot in my main post.  Also I would be HUGELY grateful if you could view another related question I posted here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231695/netbeans-environment-path-and-jdk-setup

Comment: It does not look a problem about screenshots. You may be more clear with this answer I believe : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13852140/11365529
And also I'll try to help you about other question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107247/discussion-between-rbj-and-berkancetin).